# Windows 10 2016 LTSB autounattended is removing features

Tags: windows-10, unattended, answerfile

I am trying to set writefilter/embeddedboot/keyboardfilter using the autounattended.xml file to install windows. the issue i am having is if there is no answer file and i install windows manually. when i get to the desktop and run:

```
dism /online /get-features
```

the command shows all the device lockdown features like writefilter. but if i create an autounattened.xml file and put it with the install usb. dism /online /get-features only shows Client-EmbeddedShellLauncher and nothing else. The logs does not say anything about skipping or missing the packages

my answer file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <servicing>
        <package action="install">
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft-Windows-EnterpriseSEdition" version="10.0.14393.0" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="" />
            <selection name="Microsoft-Hyper-V-ClientEdition-Package" state="false" />
        </package>
        <package action="install">
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package" version="10.0.14393.0" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="" />
            <selection name="Client-DeviceLockdown" state="true" />
            <selection name="Client-EmbeddedBootExp" state="true" />
            <selection name="Client-EmbeddedLogon" state="true" />
            <selection name="Client-EmbeddedShellLauncher" state="true" />
            <selection name="Client-KeyboardFilter" state="true" />
            <selection name="Client-UnifiedWriteFilter" state="true" />
            <selection name="LegacyComponents" state="true" />
            <selection name="DirectPlay" state="true" />
            <selection name="Microsoft-Windows-Client-EmbeddedExp-Package" state="false" />
            <selection name="Microsoft-Windows-Printing-PrintToPDFServices-Package" state="false" />
            <selection name="Microsoft-Windows-Printing-XPSServices-Package" state="false" />
            <selection name="MSRDC-Infrastructure" state="false" />
            <selection name="Printing-PrintToPDFServices-Features" state="false" />
            <selection name="Printing-Foundation-Features" state="false" />
            <selection name="Printing-XPSServices-Features" state="false" />
            <selection name="SearchEngine-Client-Package" state="false" />
            <selection name="SimpleTCP" state="true" />
            <selection name="WorkFolders-Client" state="false" />
            <selection name="Xps-Foundation-Xps-Viewer" state="false" />
        </package>
    </servicing>
    <settings pass="windowsPE">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SetupUILanguage>
                <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            </SetupUILanguage>
            <InputLocale>1009:00000409</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>en-US</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            <UILanguageFallback>en-US</UILanguageFallback>
            <UserLocale>en-CA</UserLocale>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <DiskConfiguration>
                <Disk wcm:action="add">
                    <CreatePartitions>
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>1</Order>
                            <Size>100</Size>
                            <Type>Primary</Type>
                        </CreatePartition>
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>2</Order>
                            <Type>Primary</Type>
                            <Extend>true</Extend>
                        </CreatePartition>
                    </CreatePartitions>
                    <ModifyPartitions>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Active>true</Active>
                            <Format>NTFS</Format>
                            <Label>System Reserved</Label>
                            <PartitionID>1</PartitionID>
                            <Order>1</Order>
                            <TypeID>0x27</TypeID>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Active>true</Active>
                            <Format>NTFS</Format>
                            <Label>OS</Label>
                            <Letter>C</Letter>
                            <Order>2</Order>
                            <PartitionID>2</PartitionID>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                    </ModifyPartitions>
                    <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                    <WillWipeDisk>true</WillWipeDisk>
                </Disk>
                <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
            </DiskConfiguration>
            <ImageInstall>
                <OSImage>
                    <InstallTo>
                        <PartitionID>2</PartitionID>
                        <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                    </InstallTo>
                    <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
                    <InstallToAvailablePartition>false</InstallToAvailablePartition>
                </OSImage>
            </ImageInstall>
            <UserData>
                <ProductKey>
                    <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
                    <Key></Key>
                </ProductKey>
                <AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>
                <FullName>test</FullName>
                <Organization>Panacea</Organization>
            </UserData>
            <EnableFirewall>true</EnableFirewall>
            <EnableNetwork>true</EnableNetwork>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="offlineServicing">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Embedded-EmbeddedLogon" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="NonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <AnimationDisabled>1</AnimationDisabled>
            <BrandingNeutral>32</BrandingNeutral>
            <HideAutoLogonUI>1</HideAutoLogonUI>
            <NoLockScreen>1</NoLockScreen>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Embedded-KeyboardFilterService" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="NonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <AltF4>Blocked</AltF4>
            <AltSpace>Blocked</AltSpace>
            <AltTab>Blocked</AltTab>
            <AltWin>Blocked</AltWin>
            <Application>Blocked</Application>
            <BrowserFavorites>Blocked</BrowserFavorites>
            <ControlAltDelete>Blocked</ControlAltDelete>
            <ControlEscape>Blocked</ControlEscape>
            <ControlTab>Blocked</ControlTab>
            <ControlWindowsF>Blocked</ControlWindowsF>
            <CtrlF4>Blocked</CtrlF4>
            <CtrlWin>Blocked</CtrlWin>
            <Escape>Blocked</Escape>
            <F21>Blocked</F21>
            <ForceOffAccessibility>true</ForceOffAccessibility>
            <LaunchApp1>Blocked</LaunchApp1>
            <LaunchApp2>Blocked</LaunchApp2>
            <LaunchMail>Blocked</LaunchMail>
            <LaunchMediaSelect>Blocked</LaunchMediaSelect>
            <LeftShiftLeftAltNumLock>Blocked</LeftShiftLeftAltNumLock>
            <LeftShiftLeftAltPrintScreen>Blocked</LeftShiftLeftAltPrintScreen>
            <ShiftControlEscape>Blocked</ShiftControlEscape>
            <ShiftWin>Blocked</ShiftWin>
            <Windows>Blocked</Windows>
            <WindowsB>Blocked</WindowsB>
            <WindowsBreak>Blocked</WindowsBreak>
            <WindowsC>Blocked</WindowsC>
            <WindowsComma>Blocked</WindowsComma>
            <WindowsD>Blocked</WindowsD>
            <WindowsDown>Blocked</WindowsDown>
            <WindowsE>Blocked</WindowsE>
            <WindowsEnter>Blocked</WindowsEnter>
            <WindowsEscape>Blocked</WindowsEscape>
            <WindowsF>Blocked</WindowsF>
            <WindowsF1>Blocked</WindowsF1>
            <WindowsH>Blocked</WindowsH>
            <WindowsHome>Blocked</WindowsHome>
            <WindowsI>Blocked</WindowsI>
            <WindowsJ>Blocked</WindowsJ>
            <WindowsK>Blocked</WindowsK>
            <WindowsL>Blocked</WindowsL>
            <WindowsLeft>Blocked</WindowsLeft>
            <WindowsM>Blocked</WindowsM>
            <WindowsMinus>Blocked</WindowsMinus>
            <WindowsO>Blocked</WindowsO>
            <WindowsP>Blocked</WindowsP>
            <WindowsPageDown>Blocked</WindowsPageDown>
            <WindowsPageUp>Blocked</WindowsPageUp>
            <WindowsPeriod>Blocked</WindowsPeriod>
            <WindowsPlus>Blocked</WindowsPlus>
            <WindowsQ>Blocked</WindowsQ>
            <WindowsR>Blocked</WindowsR>
            <WindowsRight>Blocked</WindowsRight>
            <WindowsShiftDown>Blocked</WindowsShiftDown>
            <WindowsShiftLeft>Blocked</WindowsShiftLeft>
            <WindowsShiftRight>Blocked</WindowsShiftRight>
            <WindowsShiftUp>Blocked</WindowsShiftUp>
            <WindowsSlash>Blocked</WindowsSlash>
            <WindowsSpace>Blocked</WindowsSpace>
            <WindowsT>Blocked</WindowsT>
            <WindowsTab>Blocked</WindowsTab>
            <WindowsU>Blocked</WindowsU>
            <WindowsUp>Blocked</WindowsUp>
            <WindowsV>Blocked</WindowsV>
            <WindowsW>Blocked</WindowsW>
            <WindowsZ>Blocked</WindowsZ>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Embedded-EmbeddedLogon" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="NonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <AnimationDisabled>1</AnimationDisabled>
            <BrandingNeutral>32</BrandingNeutral>
            <HideAutoLogonUI>1</HideAutoLogonUI>
            <NoLockScreen>1</NoLockScreen>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Embedded-BootExp" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="NonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <DisableBootMenu>1</DisableBootMenu>
            <DisplayDisabled>1</DisplayDisabled>
            <HideAllBootUI>1</HideAllBootUI>
            <HideBootLogo>1</HideBootLogo>
            <HideBootStatusIndicator>1</HideBootStatusIndicator>
            <HideBootStatusMessage>1</HideBootStatusMessage>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Embedded-UnifiedWriteFilter" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="NonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ProtectedVolumeList>
                <ProtectedVolumeEntry wcm:action="add">
                    <DriveLetter>C</DriveLetter>
                </ProtectedVolumeEntry>
            </ProtectedVolumeList>
            <AddAllVolumes>True</AddAllVolumes>
            <OverlayCriticalThreshold>10000</OverlayCriticalThreshold>
            <OverlayMaximumSize>10240</OverlayMaximumSize>
            <OverlayWarningThreshold>9000</OverlayWarningThreshold>
            <OverlayType>Disk overlay</OverlayType>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Embedded-ShellLauncher" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="NonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <UserSettings>
                <User wcm:action="add">
                    <AccountName>test</AccountName>
                    <DefaultReturnCodeAction>0</DefaultReturnCodeAction>
                    <Key>1</Key>
                    <Shell>notepad</Shell>
                </User>
            </UserSettings>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <AutoLogon>
                <Password>
                    <Value>UABAAG6QABjAGUAQABQAGEAc6BzAHcAb6ByAGQA</Value>
                    <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                </Password>
                <Domain>.</Domain>
                <Enabled>true</Enabled>
                <LogonCount>5</LogonCount>
                <Username>test</Username>
            </AutoLogon>
            <OOBE>
                <VMModeOptimizations>
                    <SkipAdministratorProfileRemoval>true</SkipAdministratorProfileRemoval>
                    <SkipNotifyUILanguageChange>true</SkipNotifyUILanguageChange>
                    <SkipWinREInitialization>true</SkipWinREInitialization>
                </VMModeOptimizations>
                <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
                <HideLocalAccountScreen>true</HideLocalAccountScreen>
                <HideOEMRegistrationScreen>true</HideOEMRegistrationScreen>
                <HideOnlineAccountScreens>true</HideOnlineAccountScreens>
                <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
                <ProtectYourPC>3</ProtectYourPC>
            </OOBE>
            <Themes>
                <WindowColor>Color 2</WindowColor>
                <DefaultThemesOff>true</DefaultThemesOff>
            </Themes>
            <UserAccounts>
                <LocalAccounts>
                    <LocalAccount wcm:action="add">
                        <Password>
                            <Value>UABAAG6QABjAGUAQABQAGEAc6BzAHcAb6ByAGQA</Value>
                            <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                        </Password>
                        <Name>test</Name>
                        <Group>Administrators</Group>
                        <DisplayName>test</DisplayName>
                    </LocalAccount>
                </LocalAccounts>
            </UserAccounts>
            <VisualEffects>
                <FontSmoothing>ClearType</FontSmoothing>
            </VisualEffects>
            <WindowsFeatures>
                <ShowInternetExplorer>false</ShowInternetExplorer>
                <ShowMediaCenter>false</ShowMediaCenter>
                <ShowWindowsMediaPlayer>false</ShowWindowsMediaPlayer>
            </WindowsFeatures>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Embedded-BootExp" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="NonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <DisableBootMenu>1</DisableBootMenu>
            <DisplayDisabled>1</DisplayDisabled>
            <HideAllBootUI>1</HideAllBootUI>
            <HideBootLogo>1</HideBootLogo>
            <HideBootStatusIndicator>1</HideBootStatusIndicator>
            <HideBootStatusMessage>1</HideBootStatusMessage>
        </component>
    </settings>
</unattend>
```

**Edit**

So it seems if i remove the configuration such as client-embedded-bootexp and both packages. It now shows up in /get-features. Is this a bug by the answer file?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information on how you are doing things, I think your package action is wrong, instead of "install" it should be "configure"

Here is an example. I should note that I seldom hand edit these files.

```
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
<servicing>
    <package action="configure">
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package" version="10.0.14393.0" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="" />
        <selection name="Microsoft-Hyper-V-Common-Drivers-Package" state="false" />
        <selection name="Microsoft-Hyper-V-Guest-Integration-Drivers-Package" state="false" />
        <selection name="Microsoft-Windows-Printing-PrintToPDFServices-Package" state="false" />
        <selection name="Microsoft-Windows-Printing-XPSServices-Package" state="false" />
        <selection name="Printing-Foundation-Features" state="false" />
        <selection name="Printing-PrintToPDFServices-Features" state="false" />
        <selection name="Printing-XPSServices-Features" state="false" />
        <selection name="SMB1Protocol" state="false" />
        <selection name="WorkFolders-Client" state="false" />
        <selection name="Xps-Foundation-Xps-Viewer" state="false" />
        <selection name="Client-DeviceLockdown" state="true" />
        <selection name="Client-EmbeddedBootExp" state="true" />
        <selection name="Client-KeyboardFilter" state="true" />
        <selection name="Client-UnifiedWriteFilter" state="true" />
    </package>
```

This is an example from a work in progress. I am using Windows System Image Manager to generate the Configuration Set with driver installs and the likes.